# How to outline bins in 2D python histogram with color map?

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to make a 2D plot in python, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the lines go along the outside of the bins, instead of through the bins. I'd like each of the boxes be outlined by lines instead. Below is my code for plotting a dataframe "df". Any help would be appreciated!

```
from matplotlib import cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
cmap = cm.get_cmap('jet', 30) # viridis
cax = ax1.imshow(df.corr(), interpolation="nearest", cmap=cmap)
ax1.grid(True, which='minor', color='black')
plt.title('Titanic Feature Correlation')
labels = [column for column in df]
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(labels,fontsize=5)
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(labels)))
ax1.set_yticklabels(labels,fontsize=5)
fig.colorbar(cax, ticks=[1, .75, .5, .25, 0, -.25, -.5, -.75, -1])
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you include an example `df`?